# $GL_1$ functor from commutative rings with 1 to Sets is corepresentable

Tags: category-theory

First denote the commutative rings with 1 whose morphisms are ring homomorphism by $\mathcal C$ and category of sets by $\mathcal{Set}$.

Define a functor$$GL_n :\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{Set}$$ On objects: $$R\mapsto GL_n(R)$$
On morphisms:
$$\quad g:R_1\to R_2\\ GL_n(g):GL_n(R_1)\to GL_n(R_2)\\ (a_{ij})\mapsto (g(a_{ij}))$$

I want to show the covariant functor taking $n=1$: $$GL_1 :\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{Set}$$ is representable.

Explicitly $GL_1\cong F_X$

In our definition for every object c in $\mathcal C$, $F_X(C)=mor(X,c)$ for a fixed $X$ in $\mathcal C$.

So I need to find a natural transformation(isomorphism) $u$ whose data consists of $u_c:mor(x,c)\to GL_1(c)$ for every $c\in \mathcal C$. To continue I cannot even find fixed ring to construct natural transformation.

Comment: Do your ring homs preserve 1?

Comment: yes let's say...

Comment: Phrase things more concretely. You want a ring $X$ such that morphisms out of $X$ can be naturally identified with...

Comment: In this special case you can also observe that $GL_1(R)$ is just the group of invertible elements of $R$. For a generic $n > 1$ things get more complicated!

Answer (score 3):

Try the ring $\mathbb{Z}[t, t^{-1}]$, the free ring on an invertible element.

More generally, for $GL_n$, view $GL_n$ as a matrix group with elements $A = (a_{ij})$, and consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\{a_{ij}\}][\det^{-1}]$, where $\det$ is the determinant of $A = (a_{ij})$ viewed as a polynomial in the variables $\{a_{ij}\}$.

Comment: So general case in a way shows that GL_n functor is corepresentable?

Comment: Yes.  Typically you would show something even more: that the corepresenting object is a cogroup, so that we can view the functor $GL_n$ landing in groups and not just sets.